# Ionic 3 build error for iOS platform - ARCHIVE FAILED

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm working with Ionic 3, iPhone 7 plus, iOS 11, and trying to build for iOS. When running `ionic cordova build ios` I'm getting this error. I've tried to remove and add the platform multiple times, without any result.

> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  Ld
>   /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/app-appdahiizzsdsdsdddoqgtygiuoqxm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/app/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Fishtank.build/Debug-iphoneos/app.build/Objects-normal/arm64/app
>   normal arm64 (1 failure) Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild
>   with args:
>   -xcconfig,/Users/user/Documents/app/Development/app/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-workspace,app.xcworkspace,-scheme,app,-configuration,Debug,-destination,generic/platform=iOS,-archivePath,app.xcarchive,archive,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/user/Documents/app/Development/app/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/user/Documents/app/Development/app/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build ios (exit code
>   1).

**Here's my ionic info:**

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.15.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.15.2
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : ios 4.5.2
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2 
ios-sim    : 5.0.12 
Node       : v7.10.0
npm        : 4.2.0 
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : legacy
```

Answer (score 3):

if your xcode account isn't "agent" try this way:

when run `ionic cordova build ios` disconnecting your iphone from your mac